# Order By DESC in SQL Query

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007

I have an embedded SQL query in a command button, I now need to add an ORDER BY [Pay_Date] DESC so it orders the most recent dates on top, however I cant seem to get it to work?  Here is what I have tried

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim strsearch As String
    Dim strText As String
    strText = Me.txtSearch.Value
    strsearch = "Select * from tblInvoiceLog where ((Vendor_Number like ""*" & strText & "*"") or (Vendor_Name like ""*" & strText & "*"") or (Invoice_1 like ""*" & strText & "*"") or (Invoice_2 like ""*" & strText & "*"") or (Invoice_3 like ""*" & strText & "*"") or (Invoice_4 like ""*" & strText & "*"") or (Invoice_5 like ""*" & strText & "*"") or (Check_Request_Total like ""*" & strText & "*"") or (Voucher_Number like ""*" & strText & "*"") or (Notes like ""*" & strText & "*"") ORDER BY ([Pay_Date] DESC))"
    Me.RecordSource = strsearch
End Sub
```

I am getting the Runtime 3075 error

Comment: You might wanna look at your parenthesis. I believe the one you open right after the WHERE keyword should be closed just before the ORDER BY starts. And you can safely skip the parenthesis from the entire ORDER BY statement.

Comment: Actually you don't need a single parenthesis in your SQL statement.

Comment: Why all the double quotes? what database are you using? trying starting and ending the string with double quotes and use single quotes inside the query.